# Phusion Passenger app preloader for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, redis, memcached, passenger

I recently switched to using Phusion Passenger 4.0.50 in replacement for Unicorn.
The reason is because Passenger integrates well with Nginx and can also power Node.js app. However, what I am wondering is if I should do anything about the external connections (with Postgresql, Redis, Memcached) like I did with Unicorn.

I found some code on the Passenger git such as [this one](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb). But this code seems to belong to Passenger rather than a Rails app.

As of now I am using Ruby 2.1.2, and Rails 4.1.6. Would such work to handle external connections still required? If it is, how should I do it?

Thanks.

#### Update:

Per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918163/do-apps-running-in-phusion-passenger-need-to-reconnect-activerecord-on-fork), it seems that normal ActiveRecord is taken cared of automatically by Passenger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. Yes you must do something about external connections. The "smart spawning" concept in Phusion Passenger is exactly the same as the "preload_app on" concept in Unicorn. We have an entire section in the documentation explaining how it works and what the caveats are (specifically, about external connections): https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#spawning_methods_explained

The only exception is the Rails default ActiveRecord connection. We automatically reestablish that, because it counts for over 90% of the use cases.

Comment: Thanks Hongli. I assume that in the case of Node.js app, I should actively disconnect and reconnect within the app.

Comment: Not with Node.js. Smart spawning is only supported for Ruby apps. With Node.js you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Passenger starts multiple sepearate worker processes, each of them loading the rails application. So each webrequest is handled by a completely isolated process within one thread. This means you don't have to care about connection pools at all. For example, in case of ActiveRecord, there are 5 concurrent connections possible by default (can be adjusted) and in your case you allways have only one connection (per process)

Comment: This is true for *direct spawn*. Would this also apply now for *smart spawn*?